# Flushing the output in GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have tried two different ways of flushing the output to the browser in GAE:

```
from time import sleep
import sys;
print ""
print "Output"
sys.stdout.flush()
sleep(10)
```

And:

```
from time import sleep
self.response.out.write("Output")
self.response.out.flush()
sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't flush the output to the browser. App Engine sends the entire response all at once when your handler returns.

Reference: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Responses

Comment: Any refrence to where it is stated? because Apache allows flushing the output. and it is a very important part of speeding up the loading of a page.

Comment: @Shedokan: added link above. App Engine isn't running Apache, and their serving infrastructure a bit more complicated than one in which the client's computer is directly connected to the server running the code.

Comment: Under #responses:
'App Engine collects all of the data the request handler script writes to the standard output stream, then waits for the script to return. When the handler completes, all of the output data is sent to the user.

App Engine does not support sending data to the user's browser before the handler returns. Some web servers use this technique to "stream" data to the user's browser over a period of time in response to a single request. App Engine does not support this streaming technique.'